# Theme.Material.Light подчёркивает красным

Tags: android, android-studio

Читаю книгу по Android. В примере нужно использовать стиль по-умолчанию:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
```

однако Android studio **Theme.Material.Light** подчёркивает красным.

Можно узнать, почему и на какой стиль можно заменить?

Кстати, также подчёркивает и android:**Theme.Holo.Light** из этого же примера.

Comment: что пишет, если навести курсор на подчеркнутое красным?

Comment: При наведении мыши пишет Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.Material.Light'

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QqxSk_hUNwZSR9d-wZvrvGMqRYLSttzy

Comment: Попробуйте указать тему в таком формате: `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light`. Не помню по какой причине, но тоже бывало, что студия ни в какую не принимала сокращённую запись. Возможно дело в версии инструментов или плагина.

Comment: Подчёркивать перестало, но выбивает приложение. Так же и на мобильном устройстве с api 22. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SGh3l_vGGzLnoHAHqWtTXA0JCZ-xYf2l

Comment: раз эта проблема решилась, @woesss может оформить ответ, а вам нужно создать другой вопрос с новой проблемой, куда приложить стектрейс при остановке приложения и связанный с этим код

Answer (score 0):

`Theme.Material.Light` поддерживается от API 21 и выше, проверьте минимальную версию SDK в `build.gradle (Module app)`, этот стиль `Theme.Holo.Light`, скорее всего устарел. Попробуйте заменить на `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: В файле /home/sergey/AndroidStudioProjects/BitsandPizzas/app/build.gradle стоит minSdkVersion 17. Т.е., мне нужно просто изменить на 21? Есть еще targetSdkVersion, она - 26. На какую обращать внимание?

Comment: Да, можете поменять minSdkVersion на 21, но в таком случае ваше приложение сможет работать на телефонах и планшетах начиная от Android 5.0 и выше.

Comment: не советуйте это или лучше обьясните. `сможет работать **только** на устройствах с 5.0+`

Comment: В книжке как раз и описывается случай, когда автоматически распознается версия устройства и подключается нужный style.xml. По-умолчанию, оно должно использовать тему Theme.Holo.Light, но если версия выше 21 (создаётся специально папка в res values-v21 и туда кладётся style.xml), то используется Theme.Material.Light. Вот обе темы подчёркиваются красным. Что такое произошло в Android Studio с момента написания книги и как продолжить обучение?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pGWeGe-i-VqIZD0vs4l8bV9gm9jAldzN